# Search is not working when pressing enter key button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using button and textbox for searching.its working good whenever I click the search button.

But if I press   enter  button then it redirects  me to another page.

I have tried  this in page load  but it's  not working:

```
Page.RegisterHiddenField("__EVENTTARGET", "btnSearch")


Page.RegisterHiddenField("__EVENTTARGET", btnSearch.uniqueid)
```

And  also this

```
 Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
    cs.RegisterHiddenField("__EVENTTARGET", searchbtn.UniqueID)
```

Please tell me how we  can do this.

Comment: Have you tried DefaultButton property on your search form?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `DefaultButton` attribute for the form if you want to handle it whole form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
```

you can also set different default button for different panel:

```
<asp:Panel id="panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="bt1">
```

for disabling button in login page(in page load of login page):

```
Button mpbtnSearch= (Button) Master.FindControl("btnSearch");
mpbtnSearch.UseSubmitBehavior=false;
```

in master page page load

```
 if(Request.Url.Host.Contains("login.aspx"))
 { 
   btnSearch.UseSubmitBehavior=false;
 }
```

Comment: thanks but problem is that this search button is on master page if i will set DefaultButton="btnSearch" in master page then it will shows its effect on whole project.So what  i need to do.

Comment: do you want to make it for any specific page ?

Comment: you can put a check (if statement ) in the master page... if its login page then set button's  `UseSubmitBehavior = "false"`

Comment: use the updated code inside page load of login page.